# How do I use the find command to list world writable files in a directory without traversing into any sub-directories?

Tags: shell-script, find

The solution to this problem has been evading me for weeks. I am attempting to write a command to find only world writable files in a specific set of directories without traversing into any sub directories using `-prune`.

I have attempted a multitude of different options only to be left with

```
find / -type f -perm -2
```

This however, still traverses into the sub-directories. Using the command

```
find / -prune -type f -perm -2
```

yields no results either. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: This stackoverflow question may help clarify how to use -prune: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh

Answer (score 4):

Try using `maxdepth N` instead:

> -**maxdepth levels**
>                 Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of
>                 directories below the starting-points.  -maxdepth 0
>                  means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points
>                 themselves.

```
find $FOLDER -maxdepth 1 -perm -2
```

Comment: Add `-mindepth 1`, otherwise you're also matching the starting directory itself. (It doesn't matter if the only action is behind a `-type f` of course.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> find / -type f -perm -2
> ```

This is recursive. That's what `find` does.

> ```
> find / -prune -type f -perm -2
> ```

Here, you're instructing `find` to apply `-prune` to everything it finds. The conditions and actions are processed from left to right; since there's no condition before `-prune`, it's applied unconditionally. So the first thing that `find` finds, which is the command line argument `/`, has `-prune` applied to it, and so `find` doesn't traverse the content of the directory. Since `/` doesn't match the following conditions, it isn't printed.

To process only the entries of the toplevel directory, you need to apply `-prune` to the directories *except the command line arguments*. The portable way to do this is to use `/.` at the end of path passed on the command line. This causes `find` to treat their name as `.`, so you can use `-name .` to match them. In a recursive traversal, no file is ever called `.` since this name is reserved. Now there are three different cases:

- Toplevel directory: recurse.
- Other directory: don't recurse.
- Regular file that are world-writable: print.

To specify several different behaviors, use the `-o` (“or”) operator. The first one for which all conditions match applies.

```
find /. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type f -perm -2 -print
```

Some versions of `find` allow you to write `find / -name / -o -type d -prune -o …` but some don't (e.g. BusyBox).

Some versions of `find` support options `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` to constrain the recursive traversal. If your find supports it, you can use this instead of `-prune`.

```
find / -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -2
```

(`-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` are global options, the conditions-and-actions part is `-type f -perm -2` with the implicit trailing `-print`.)

Comment: Much appreciated Gilles! This does exactly what I need it to. Min and Maxdepth are not an option as our environment uses several flavors of *nix.